# SQL Server 2019 does not find folder when path contains spaces, and adding quotes does not solve the issue

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I've got a package deployed to SQL Server for which the flat file destinations contain a space, for example: \\SERVER\Cheesy Beans On Toast\

The package adds the file name to the end of the string using an expression in the connection, so the final path is: \\SERVER\Cheesy Beans On Toast\TheFile.txt

I can run this package directly from Visual Studio no problems, but once deployed as SQL Server 2019, and run it from a job using the Service Agent, I get this error message on the stage that is supposed to create the output file:

Cannot open the datafile "\\SERVER\Cheesy Beans On Toast\TheFile.txt".

That same job runs perfectly when I rename the folder to CheesyBeansOnToast (no spaces) and update the environment variable accordingly.

Unfortunately, the final destination for this project will be on a server where the folders contain spaces, and I have no power to alter this.

I have tried adding single and double quotes around the connection string, but whether I do this in the connection string expression or the variable that gets fed in to the connection string expression, I just get a different error:

The file name ""\\SERVER\Cheesy Beans On Toast\TheFile.txt"" specified in the connection was not valid.

So it is picking up my extra quotes, but rather than helping with the spaces it instead fails to recognise the path as valid at all.

Any ideas on either how to get the package deployed on SQL Server to just accept the spaces in the same way that running it directly from Visual Studio does, or how to make SQL Server understand a path with spaces in when adding quotes around it seems to do nothing? I would love to just rename the target folders but as mentioned that is out of my control.

Comment: Your second string looks like it has one quote too many at the beginning.

Comment: User account which is used by SQL Server Agent to execute the package has no access to the folder. Check actual error messages, not this stub.

Comment: Apologies Ian Kemp, I cannot paste from my Citrix connection to my browser with stack overflow open, in reality there are only 2 double quotes at the start of the second error message, not three.

Comment: Hi Roger, I renamed the folder to add and remove the spaces while I was testing, and checked that the SQL Agent had access all the time. It runs in the version with no spaces, and the version with spaces has identical permissions so I'm not sure this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved! SQL Agent seems to need not only NTFS access but also Share access. When folders were renamed, the Share access must have dropped.

I was not able to view anything about Share access because I was not an administrator, I could only see the NTFS permissions, so I was not aware anything had changed.

After the administrator had put the Share access on, it then worked.